# Prevent clang from replacing my code with library calls

Tags: optimization, assembly, arm, clang, llvm

Clang optimizes the code by replacing some parts with efficient library functions.

For example the following code:

```
for (i=0;i<size;++i)
       dest[i]=src[i];
```

will be compiled to (target=ARM assembly):

```
bl      __aeabi_memcpy(PLT)
```

I tried using -fno-builtin and -O0 without success.

Is there a flag or some other way to prevent the compiler from replacing the code with library calls?

Comment: Strange. I can't get clang to call the function with a small test case. Do you have a test case that generates that code? What command line arguments are you using?

Comment: The cmd line:

'/usr/share/android-arm-l14-toolchain/bin/clang31 -cc1 -triple arm-none-linux-androideabi -S -target-abi aapcs-linux -target-cpu arm1022e -backend-option -arm-enable-ehabi -backend-option -arm-enable-ehabi-descriptors -backend-option -arm-ignore-has-ras  -internal-isystem /usr/share/android-arm-l14-toolchain/lib/clang/3.1/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/share/android-arm-l14-toolchain/bin/../sysroot/usr/include -o myMemcpy.s -x c myMemcpy.c'

Comment: Many of your command line options seem to be obsolete: current clang (3.5) doesn't recognize them. I see you're using 3.1. Maybe you should get a newer version of clang?

Comment: But how would it solve my problem?

Comment: I'm not sure. As I said I was not able to duplicate it with 3.5.

Comment: -disable-simplify-libcalls during optimization?

Comment: The compiler doesn't recognize the "disable-simplify-libcalls" flag. Can you please try and reproduce the problem? Use the code and build cmd above.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21318229/llvm-optimizes-with-library-functions

Comment: I downloaded the latest NDK that includes arm-linux-androideabi-clang 3.4 and compiled with  "-fno-builtin" and "-O0" flags and it still calls memcpy. The flag "-disable-simplify-libcalls" is not known to clang.
I use the following cmd to compile: 'arm-linux-androideabi-clang myMemcpy.c -S'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its seems like a syntax bug in clang. You must use optimization flag together with the *no-builtin* flag.

The following command produces assembly **with** a call to memcopy:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-clang -S myMemcpy.c -fno-builtin
```

The following command produces assembly **without** a call to memcopy:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-clang -S myMemcpy.c -fno-builtin -O1
```

The *no-builtin* flag is coupled with the optimization flag.